# ASP.Net Localization for those dynamically added by javascript

Tags: asp.net

I know that adding a localization on resource file is the way to handle multiple languages for the asp.net application. But how about those dynamically added via javascript?

1. Should I add a json file counterpart of the resource file? 
   -This will be redundant right?
2. Should I just read/access the resource file from the javascript?
   -I greatly consider this solution.

Are there any other solution? Best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I am on the localization team at Lynda.com

Resource files are great for lookups and speed but can get old or stale if you have a dynamic website that has langauges being localized daily.

I would suggest storing your languages in mongodb. Where you have a 
Key = The Page Name
A culture Field
And an array containing values

Example:

```
key: "home-page" {
   "en-US": {
       homePageHeader:"Hello welcome to ...",
       okButton: "OK"

   }
}
```

Comment: Well I am using SQL server already and I cant change it due to business reasons. So, do you still suggest to store it on SQL server? Re the javascript which added text dynamically, how should I load the localization from the server? Ajax?